# create a json dynamically in node js

Tags: node.js, json, hubspot

I have a problem with creating a json dynamically. I retrieve the data of a sent json:
body.value look like :

```
  {
    hubspotProperty: 'question3',
    response: 'Nous utilisons un google drive mais il est très peu utilisé'
  },
  {
    hubspotProperty: 'question2',
    response: 'Nous complétons le CRM quand nous avons ' +
      'le temps et au bon vouloir du commercial'
  },
  {
    hubspotProperty: 'question1',
    response: "Nous n'avons aucun processus " +
      "automatisé et nous n'en voyons pas " +
      "l'intérêt"
  }
]
```

but I want the hubspot property to be the key of the new json and the response to be my I don't now how I can do this .
Help me please

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour, the simplest way to make json:

```
var someValue = "Jean"
var jsonString = `{"nom":"${someValue}"}`
```

Take care of the "backwards ticks" `

Regarding the json which comes in to you:

```
var exampleJson = `{ "hubspotProperty": "question3" }`
```

It is this easy ...

```
 var args = JSON.parse(exampleJson)

 var value = args.hubspotProperty

 console.log("it's done .. " + value)
```